# How can I get an iPhone‘s equipment supervision model like A1532 via code？

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, itunes, jailbreak

Recently I need to produce a Mac software to get an iPhone device information，but I can't get the equipment supervision model via code.
I use [mobileDeviceManager](https://github.com/xslim/mobileDeviceManager) to get the information what I need.There is a sample code:

```
- (NSString*)serialNumber {
    return [self deviceValueForKey:@"SerialNumber"];
}
// Returns an informational value from the device's root domain.
// @param key can apparently be any value like DeviceName...
```

Unfortunately，I can not find the key to get the value of equipment supervision model.Can I get the equipment supervision mode from a no jailbreak iPhone via code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

+ (NSString *)deviceName {
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: it's print "x86_64"……I think maybe it tell us the mac's info

Comment: Possibly I misunderstood the question. My code is for iOS app.

Comment: so do you any idea about Mac app?

Comment: Unfortunately no, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your friendly answer.